# How to show Emoji such as ☔ and  in a Microsoft MFC CListCtrl?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc, emoji, clistctrl

I'm developing a desktop application with MFC CListctrl, build with Unicode.

The listctrl can correctly show ！＠＃＄％︿＆＊（） ,
but not Emojis ☔ and .

It's a "virtual listctrl" and the lvItem.pszText seems correctly holding in memory the UNICODE "26 14" for ☔, but not showing correctly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks!

[EDITED 20140929]

Thanks Werner Henze, I have found out that "Segoe UI Symbol" can show emoji correctly in Windows 7 http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120818/microsoft-backports-windows-8-emoji-for-segoe-ui-symbol-to-windows-7/

```
Microsoft KB2729094 titled “An update for the Segoe UI symbol font in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2 is available” is presumed to be made available through Windows Update soon.
```

However "Segoe UI Symbol" seems to failed on Korean characters(which is correctly shown with "Segoe UI").

Comment: Emoji requires DirectWrite, MFC does not wrap it.  MFC is pretty stuck with user32.  It isn't integrated with any desktop class library that I know of.

Comment: Can DirectWrite be used in an owner-drawn list box? (I don't see a reason why it may not, but nevertheless always safer to ask .)

Comment: It is certainly technically possible.  But this complaint-based programming, a chorus of programmers having to learn COM, QA writing bug reports for inconsistent text rendering and users bitching about the readability of the text on their cheap monitors spoil the fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind.

First your program should use `RegisterWindowW` and not `RegisterWindowA` so your window is instantiated as a Unicode window. This is done automatically for the MFC provided main window classes if you are compiling for Unicode.

Second you must choose a font that is capable of displaying the required characters. You can check which font is in use and maybe change it with this code snippet (in my code taken from OnCreate):

```
CFont * pFont = m_listctrl.GetFont();
ASSERT((HFONT)m_fontListLog == nullptr);
LOGFONT logfont;
VERIFY(pFont->GetLogFont(&logfont));
_tcscpy(logfont.lfFaceName, _T("my desired font"));
VERIFY(m_font.CreateFontIndirect(&logfont));
m_listctrl.SetFont(&m_font);
```

You can check which font supports which characters with `charmap.exe`.

I tested successfully with font "Segoe UI" and character 0x214e, but could not output your 0x2614 because the font does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Werner Henze,
I have found out that "Segoe UI Symbol" can show emoji correctly in Windows 7
http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120818/microsoft-backports-windows-8-emoji-for-segoe-ui-symbol-to-windows-7/

> Microsoft KB2729094 titled “An update for the Segoe UI symbol font in
>   Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2 is available” is presumed to
>   be made available through Windows Update soon.

However "Segoe UI Symbol" seems to failed on Korean characters(which is correctly shown with "Segoe UI").

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Comment: Thank you Ed Cottrell and Monacraft, I edited to my question and will delete this answer.